# Mixing dynamic and fixed items in Silverlight TreeView

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, treeview

I'm attempting to create a TreeView in Silverlight that contains both fixed elements and databound ones. I am able to produce one that creates the desired effect, but it's not perfect - it highlights parent+child nodes as a single TreeViewItem.

The effect I am trying to achieve is:

`PersonName

|-Age:

|-Hair Colour:

|-Pets

| |-PetName

| | |-Species:

| | |-Size:

| |-PetName

| . |-Species:

| . |-Size:

|-Friends

. |-Name:

. |-Favourite Comic:`

So elements like 'Pets' and 'Friends' should always appear for a person, with their items beneath them. How can these be templated?

I've looked at the example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) but it only has static elements above the databound ones. If the structure was `DataboundConference-->Teams-->TeamName,TeamName,TeamName` instead of `DataboundConference-->TeamName,TeamName,TeamName`, it'd be exactly what I wanted.

I hope I've explained this correctly...